# Decimal seprarator is changed by ggplot2 in R Kernel of jupyter

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I am using jupyter and R with ggplot for some data analysis. Everything seems to work fine, however as soon as I am trying to show a ggplot file the decimal separator afterwards is changed to comma instead of point (ie showing 0,5 instead of 0.5) The comma is used in Germany for decimals but I really need the decimal point.

Jupyter QtConsole 4.4.2

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)

In [1](https://github.com/JenniferHemmerich/ggplot2_jupyter/blob/master/Error_ggplot2.ipynb): library('ggplot2')

In [2]: a <- c(0.5,0.6)

...: a

[1](https://github.com/JenniferHemmerich/ggplot2_jupyter/blob/master/Error_ggplot2.ipynb) 0.5 0.6

In [3]: pl <- ggplot()+
   ...: geom_line(aes(x=c(0,1),y=c(1,0)))

In [4]: a

[1](https://github.com/JenniferHemmerich/ggplot2_jupyter/blob/master/Error_ggplot2.ipynb) 0.5 0.6

In [5]: pl <- ggplot()+

...: geom_line(aes(x=c(0,1),y=c(1,0)))

...: pl

[5] #"Plot shown here"

In [6]: a

[1](https://github.com/JenniferHemmerich/ggplot2_jupyter/blob/master/Error_ggplot2.ipynb) 0,5 0,6

Here is the original file: [gist](https://github.com/JenniferHemmerich/ggplot2_jupyter/blob/master/Error_ggplot2.ipynb)

It would be great to get feedback on whats going on here. Did I forget to set an option for inline plotting?

Comment: Can you run this and tell me the output? `getOption("OutDec")`. If it shows "comma", you can change them to "dot" using `options(OutDec='.')`

Comment: It shows always '.' .  Setting the parameter also does not change the printed output. I have Updated the gist accordingly trying to output it after every step.